# By Holder inequality, show that $2\sin^2\lambda - \lambda \sin(2\lambda)\leq 2\lambda^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

> **Question**: By using Holder's inequality, prove that for any real number $\lambda,$
>   $$4\sin^2\lambda - \lambda \sin(2\lambda)\leq 2\lambda^2.$$

Assume that $\lambda\geq 0.$
Since Holder's inequality involves integral, I try to obtain $f(x)$ such that 
$$\int_0^\lambda f(x)\,dx = 4\sin^2(\lambda) - \lambda \sin(2\lambda).$$
By using first fundamental theorem of calculus and [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff%204%5Csin%5E2(%5Clambda)%20-%20%5Clambda%20%5Csin(2%5Clambda)), I obtain that 
$$f(\lambda)= 3\sin(2\lambda) - 2\lambda \cos(2\lambda).$$
Therefore, by Holder's inequality,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\lambda 3\sin(2x) - 2x \cos(2x)\,dx & \leq \left( \int_0^\lambda (3\sin(2x) - 2x \cos(2x))^2  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\int_0^\lambda 1^2 \, dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& =\sqrt{\lambda}\left(  \int_0^\lambda 9\sin^2(2x) - 12x\sin(2x)\cos(2x) + 4x^2\cos^2(2x)  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& \leq \sqrt{\lambda} \left( \int_0^\lambda 9 +6x+4x^2\,dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
& = \sqrt{\lambda} \left(9\lambda + 3\lambda^2+ \frac{4}{3}\lambda^3\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{align}
However, it does not seem like the inequality 
$$9\lambda^2 + 3\lambda^3+\frac{4}{3}\lambda^4 \leq 4\lambda^4$$
holds.
The following is their graphs.

[image]

So I run out of idea to prove the inequality. 
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $$f(\lambda) = 4 \sin(2 \lambda) - 2 \lambda \cos(2 \lambda)$$

Comment: @Mattos: I obtained $f(\lambda)$ from Wolfram. Did I input wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{3\sin(2x) - 2x \cos(2x)}{4x},\quad \text{and} \quad g(x)=4x.
\end{equation}
We apply Hölder's inequality on the interval $[0,\lambda]$ for $\lambda > 0$:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\lambda f(x)g(x)\,dx \le ||fg||_1 \le ||f||_\infty ||g||_1.
\end{equation}
The supremum of $|f|$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$, and $||g||_1 = 2 \lambda^2$, so
\begin{equation}
4 \sin^2 \lambda - \lambda \sin(2\lambda) \le 2 \lambda^2
\end{equation}
for all $\lambda > 0$.  The result is trivial for $\lambda = 0$, and the functions in the inequality are even, so the inequality holds for all real $\lambda$.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to differentiate right hand side to obtain $g.$